# python executable generator using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, executable, pyinstaller, reverse-shell

I am making a program to generate an executable that runs a reverse shell when run but I need this program to get input from the user(xxx = port, xxx.xxx.x.x = IP address) and create an executable using said data. I would like to use pyinstaller but i need advice on how to do so